# show subcategories of parent category when no subcategories in category page

Tags: magento-1.9, layered-navigation

In magento when we click on a category it takes us to category page and shows
(if exists) subcategories of the clicked category in layered navigation on left.But when we click on a category that has no subcategories it show empty on that category page in layered navigation on left. What I want is to show subcategories of the parent if the current category has no subcategories.For this I have done the following but did not work for me.

I have tried to add the following to to

app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Layer/Filter/Category.php

```
if(count($categoty->getChildrenCategories())){
    $categories = $categoty->getChildrenCategories();
}else{
    $categories = $categoty->getParentCategory()->getChildrenCategories();
}
```

and removed line #163

```
$categories = $categoty->getChildrenCategories();
```

Please suggest me a solution. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution. I have to put the above login in left.phtml

```
app/design/frontend/theme/template/catalog/navigation/left.phtml


 $categoty = Mage::registry('current_category');
    $categories = $category->getChildrenCategories();
    //$_categories = $this->getCurrentChildCategories();

     if(count($categoty->getChildrenCategories())){
        $_categories = $categoty->getChildrenCategories();
     }else{
         $_categories = $categoty->getParentCategory()->getChildrenCategories();
     }
```

and it worked like a charm! Hope it will help someone else!